# Add field to json in Postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I recieve json object as a response from a service (request 1).
I need to add extra field to it and to send it again (lets' call it "request 2").
I have applied this code to responseBody of "request 1":

```
var jsonData=JSON.parse(responseBody);
jsonData.back_uri= "http:\/\/192.168.2.3\/newpage\/";
```

I can't make postman add new node to top level of json, new field every time get node2 as a parent. I need new field to be next to "field11" or "field1". 
Here is original Json from "request1"

```
{
    "field1": 1,
    "field_2": "09.28.2018",
    "node1": {
        "field3": 1,
        "field4": "09.08.2018",
        "node1-2": [
            {
                "field5": 1,
                "field6": 1
            }
        ]
    },
        "node2": {
        "field7": 1,
        "field8": "09.08.2018",
        "node2-2": [
            {
                "field9": 1,
                "field10": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "field11": ""
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: The only JSON involved is stored in `responseBody`. Anything else isn't JSON but a regular object.

Comment: Satya, I don't get an error, new filed became a child of a node2, but I need it to be in the top, like "field11". As I understand, I need to add a filed to an oblect.

Comment: Can we see what you get back in `responseBody` please. What you sent originally is largely irrelevant because you're talking about adding something to that response, not to the original.

Comment: listed code is responseBody as is. Corrently I have solved the task by cutting last } from response text and adding ,"fieldname":"value"} to the end of it.

Comment: Ok sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you were saying what was shown was what you had sent originally. I don't know how PostMan's JS engine works exactly, but using normal JS in the browser then what you have shown already should work. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/px208m7v/

Answer (score 0):

Corrently I have solved the task by cutting last } from response text and adding ,"fieldname":"value"} to the end of it. Till someone would not share a better idea, it could help somebody else.

Comment: You can use Object.assign() to dynamically add new property to object. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign